# How to construct the confidence band for a timebased sample of n individuals

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, mean, random-variable, sample

Let $X^{(i)}(t)$ be some measurement at time $t$ for individual $i$.

Let $\bar{X}(t) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X^{(i)}(t)$ be the mean of the individuals at time $t$.

Let $\bar{X}_{t_0} = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=t_0}^T \bar{X}(t)$ be the pooled (or *grand*) mean taken from time $t=t_0$ and up to time $t=T$.

I now want to plot $\bar{X}(t) - \bar{X}_{t_0}$ for all values $t$, and construct a confidence interval at each time (resulting in a confidence band).

If I did not have the $\bar{X}_{t_0}$ term I would just use a t-quantile, but due to this term, I am unsure of how to construct the confidence intervals. It is assumed that $X^{(i)}(t)$ will tend to some fixed random variable as $t$ cross some threshold value $t_0$ (which is unknown). The resulting random variable is not necesarily the same for different individuals (not sure if this information is relevant).

*How would I proceed to construct such a confidence band?*